# How to eleminate access voilation writing location

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012

I am dealing with arrays of size ((128*75)*(128*75)) in C.Whenever I declared the array as global,there is no issue like

```
#include<stdio.h>
float buf[(128*75)*(128*75)]
int main()
{
   //using buf in different functions works fine
}
```

But whenever i declared it using malloc and using in main() getting access violation writing location error,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   float * buf;
   buf = malloc((128*75)*(128*75));

   //using buf in different functions gives error
}
```

What is the reason for it?

Comment: you do not allocate enough memory for your array.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(float)*(128*75)*(128*75));`

Comment: ...and check `malloc` return value `!= NULL` and free the memory before the end of program.

Comment: why not use a breakpoint and check it yourself?!

Comment: Thanks,it's working now.

Answer (score 5):

`malloc(x)` only reserves `x` **bytes**, not `x` **floats**.

The global arrays is indeed 128*75*128*75 floats in size. The malloc-ed buffer is only 128*75*128*75 **bytes** in size, i.e. can only contain one fourth of the required number of floats (assuming a float is 4 bytes on your platform).

That is why you probably access beyond the limits of the malloc-ed buffer and get a segfault/access violation or whatever it is called on your platform.

You can use `calloc()` or you can use a size of `128*75*128*75*sizeof(float)` as argument to `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

first, why not do:

```
int size = 128*75*128*75;
float buf[size];
```

second, check `buf != NULL` before using it, because malloc may have failed (if malloc failed, you will get NULL as return value - so you may miss that, if the array you tried to use is too big - you'll get compilation error - can't miss)

third, use `sizeof` inside malloc: `buf = malloc(sizeof(float)*size);` (as said by others, malloc allocates bytes and when declaring array - the compiler knows the type of element you want, so it gives you array with that size - meaning `int a[2]` size is `2*sizeof(int)` but `malloc(2)` size is 2 bytes which is smaller